# Unable to add caption to Calculated Fields in "Field section" of Webdatarocks pivot table

Tags: webdatarocks

Unable to add caption to Calculated Fields in "Field section" of Webdatarocks pivot table.
Non-calculated fields comes with caption but caption doesn't works for Calculated fields.
Note : In table caption works fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have created a report with calculated fields. In my example, captions work well both in `FieldList` and on the grid.

You can take a look and compare it with your one: [link to CopePen](https://codepen.io/webdatarocks/pen/YzeNaaj).